# How could display 4 bytes unicode in org of emacs

Tags: emacs

The following 4 bytes unicode characters are not displayed properly

```
alert( ''.length ); // 2, MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT CAPITAL X
alert( ''.length ); // 2, FACE WITH TEARS OF JOY
alert( ''.length ); // 2, a rare Chinese hieroglyph
```

They are just shown as messy code.

How could get them displayed？

Comment: https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/unicode-ligatures-color-emoji

Comment: What OS are you running Emacs on? I can see all three characters when I paste the code into my Emacs running on Ubuntu.

Comment: run wsl-ubuntu on windows @legoscia